# syntax error, unexpected token ";", expecting ")"

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to display a list of users in a table and provide a link for each user to view their details on a separate page. However, I get a parse error

Here are my codes

User list page:

```
<table class="user-list-table table">
        <thead class="table-light">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Admin</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($users as $item)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>
              <a 
              href="{{ route('user-view', ['id' => $item->id] }}">
              {{ $item->name }}
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->password }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->phone_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->is_admin }}</td>

          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

The UserController:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('main.user.user-view-account')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

The route to main.user.user-view-account:

```
Route::get('user-view/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('user-view');
```

I'm trying to route user to user/id/view, can anybody see what is causing the error please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your Anchor tag you need to close your `route`

```
<a 
  href="{{ route('user-view', ['id' => $item->id]) }}"
>
  {{ $item->name }}
</a>
```